# Caddy web server fastcgi with virtual hosts

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to configure Caddy FastCGI with multiple virtual hosts. As far as I can tell the following Caddyfile should be working:

```
gzip
tls support@mydomain.com
errors /var/log/caddy/error.log

header / Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;"

portal.mydomain.info {
    fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:3000 {
        root /var/www/portal
        ext .php
        index index.php
    }
}

urlf.mydomain.info {
    fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:3001 {
        root /var/www/urlf
        ext .php
        index index.php
    }
}
```

But Caddy is failing to start with error:

```
Feb  2 04:33:58 ip-172-31-24-38 caddy[3135]: 2018/02/02 04:33:58 /etc/caddy/Caddyfile:7 - Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'portal.mydomain.info'
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the Caddyfile tutorial](https://caddyserver.com/tutorial/caddyfile):

> The first line of the Caddyfile is always the address of the site to serve.

So you'll need to restructure your Caddyfile so all directives are inside a site definition. [Here's a page describing the syntax in more technical (and visual) detail.](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile)